# How to configure Vim TypeScript syntax to be a strict superset of JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vim

I'm reworking my Vim setup and am looking for a way to add TS syntax highlighting as a strict superset of the existing JS configs. For example, if I set strings to be one color in JS, they should be that same color in TS without having to configure them separately. All shared syntax should be highlighted the same with the same groups. Syntax highlighting should reflect the nature of the languages.

However, what I've found is quite the opposite. Vim seemingly ships with [yats](https://github.com/HerringtonDarkholme/yats.vim) by default, which boasts this tagline:

> Exuberant Highlighting. The most elaborate or byzatine syntax highlighting for TypeScript.

This is just about the exact opposite of what I want (and I fail to see why anyone else would desire this).

Looking at the highlighting groups shows an utter disconnect from the underlying language. Why would I want to set `typescriptEndColons`, for example? There is no `javascriptEndColons`. Yats seemingly has increased the complexity 10 fold just for the sake of "being elaborate".

Is there anyway to use a TS syntax highlighter as a strict superset? It should only be concerned with things like types, generics, etc. Everything that is standard JS should be handled by existing JS syntax highlighters for consistency's sake.

Comment: Opened an issue in Vim to discuss the merits of using `yats` by default while it has very different standards to the underlying JS highlighting: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/10976

Comment: Vim uses yats because it exists and an existing syntax script is more valuable than one you have to create. If you want an alternative approach you will have to write it yourself and make a convincing PR.

Comment: Honestly I'm pretty horrified to realize a project as old and presumably established as Vim has such a cavalier "use it because it exists" attitude. I'd expect that from a hacker, not an official distribution of syntax plugins. No norms or quality control checks doesn't reflect well. Regardless, your response adds little. I'm aware I could write my own, but I imagine others have ran into this issue as well and was hopeful for an existing solution (even if niche). No, I'm not willing to dig Vim out upstream over this even if I had the time to throw at it.

Comment: Well, we all run into all kinds of issues with open source software. I guess we should all feel lucky that some of us actually do something to address them instead of just complaining. Anyway, confronting one's assumptions/expectations with reality is a good thing.

Comment: I very publicly do a lot, thanks. It's not a complaint, but a criticism; I've very clearly outlined the problems, why they're problems, and a path forward for improving this. I'm not merely stating "I don't like this" and to say I am is disingenuous and shows bad faith. If you want to continue your decade of toxic behavior on all things Vim, be my guest, but don't do it here.